# free() function with descriptors

Tags: c, sockets

Can we use free() with parameter being a descriptor like a socket descriptor or a file descriptor to free the space in memory. In general what will we do to free space of any descriptor.

Comment: The argument to `free` in `stdlib` must be a pointer.  If you want custom behavior, you should wrap the `free` function in one of your own.

Comment: Is this descriptor a pointer to an address returned by malloc(), calloc(), or realloc()? If not, no.

Comment: You use whatever function is documented to close the descriptor based on which function was used to open it in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we use free() with parameter being a descriptor like a socket
>   descriptor or a file descriptor to free the space in memory. In
>   general what will we do to free space of any descriptor.

No.  To free a socket or file descriptor on most platforms, you must call `close(int)`.

On Windows only, you need to instead call `closesocket(int)` to close a socket.  (Windows does not support unix-style `int` file descriptors)

That's the only way to do it.